# How to bind data to html in angular 2/4 by using thread or async

Tags: multithreading, angular

I have a Component, which have child component. at ngOnInit() I'm calling Web API and get list of data.

Initial point length of the list is 10, But it will have more.

Need to execute some method (task|process|job) in background to take rest of the data 10 by 10 in a loop which would run parallel to other task in background no matter what the user is currently doing, which component he/she is interacting with. And execute that method so that it doesn't block others.

What is the correct way to do this?

Comment: Hello and welcome to StackOverflow. Please take some time to read the help page, especially the sections named ["What topics can I ask about here?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and ["What types of questions should I avoid asking?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask). And more importantly, please read [the Stack Overflow question checklist](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/156810/204922). You might also want to learn about [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Examples](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Thanks Anuresh,
I'll read above Helps and Improve my questions.

Answer (score 0):

Seems like a recursive call to me !

```js
firstResults: any[] = []; // First 10 results to show to your user
results: any[] = []; // All results
currentPosition = 0; // The current position of your last result fetched

getData() {
  this.myService.getResults().subscribe(results => {
    if(!this.firstResults.length) {
      this.firstResults = results
    }
    this.results.push(...results);
    this.currentPosition += results.length;
    this.getData();
  });
}
```

Comment: Thanks trichetriche,
No issues with Recursive, I need to get data on a thread. with out blocks  User interacting with the application.

Answer (score 0):

I don't imagine you're trying to do. But if the list is not so largger, you can get all the data and "paginate" the array

```
allData:any[];
page:number=0; //page is 0,1,2,3,4....
paginateData:any[]
this.httpClient.get("url").subscribe(res=>{
     allData=res;
     paginateData=allData.slice(10*this.page,10*(this.page+1));
}
```

Comment: Thanks Eliseo,
My issue is Using Thread, Because The List may contain 1000 of data. here I mention 10 by 10 as a example. It may vary according to situation.